# Image manipulation in Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to get the starter example opencv laplace:

```
import cv
im = cv.LoadImageM("building.jpg", 1)
dst = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 3)
laplace = cv.Laplace(im, dst)
cv.SaveImage("foo-laplace.png", dst)
```

for all images in a directory.

Sofar I got the glob.glob part:

```
li =[]
li = glob.glob('/path/*.jpg')

for x in li:
    im = cv.LoadImage( x + ".png", 1)
    dst = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 3);
    laplace = cv.Laplace(im, dst)
    cv.SaveImage("laplacian"+ x + ".png", dst)
```

Any suggestions on how this could work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

im = cv.LoadImage( x + ".png", 1)

you dont add  ".png"

im = cv.LoadImage( x , 1)